# JSON data from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, highcharts, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using Highcharts to display other graphs from csv's in my application, but now I have to access JSON data from a url (test.com/data/data1,temp) and i'm not sure how to best tackle this scenario.

The JSON data is formatted as such:

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"2013-10-01 00:00:00": 19.6}, {"2013-10-01 01:00:00": 19.1}, {"2013-10-01 02:00:00": 18.4}, {"2013-10-01 03:00:00": 17.9}, {"2013-10-01 04:00:00": 17.5}, {"2013-10-01 05:00:00": 17.2}, {"2013-10-01 06:00:00": 17.2}, {"2013-10-01 07:00:00": 17.4}]}
```

and i have set up a form to input the url (as there are 30 locations) to generate each chart. I'm also not sure on how best to separate the two results, e.g.. the first being 'date' the second 'temperature'.

```
@data = JSON.parse(open("test.com/data/data1,temp").read)

    @dates = Array.new
    @temperatures = Array.new

    @data['data'].each do |d|
      @dates.push(d.keys)
      @temperatures.push(d.values)
    end

    @graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.chart(:height => '300')
      f.yAxis [:title => {:text => "Temperature", :margin => 20, style: { color: '#333'}}]
      f.series(:type => 'line', :name => 'Temperature', :data => @temperatures)
      f.xAxis(:categories => @dates, labels: {overflow: 'justify', :rotation => 90, :step => 10} )
    end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best practice, but you can store dates in an array and temperatures in an other one like this :

```
# Considering you already stored your data, you need to parse it now
data = JSON.parse(your_data)

# Initialize your two arrays
@dates = Array.new
@temperatures = Array.new

# Fill your two arrays
data["data"].each do |d|
  @dates.push(d.keys)
  @temperatures.push(d.values.to_i) # Need to be a number to work with .series of HightCharts
end
```

Now you have the `@dates` array which contains all your dates and `@temperatures` array which contains all your temperatures.

Hope this help !

Comment: Thanks Kilian, has helped immensely. Although I can not display the values data in the graph. Code updated.

Comment: I think it's because HighChart wants number for series (I forget that details). So try to force value of @temperatures as integer like that `@temperatures.push(d.values.to_i)`